# rspec yield block, but call original

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec, block, yield

So I have the following:

```
foo.each do |f|
  f.begin
    do_stuff
    do_more_stuff
  end
end
```

And I mock the f object with an and_yield() call. I want to be able to test the begin method by passing it the original block { do_stuff do_more_stuff }, not a mock implementation.... I cant just let the begin method be called on the mock without at least stubbing it, so what do I do?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Again, an undocumented feature that i found:

```
allow(thing).to receive(:foo) do |_, &block|
  block.call
end
```

le sigh....

Comment: Not undocumented: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-1/docs/configuring-responses/block-implementation

Comment: Awesomesauce! I guess I am just blind

Comment: With RSpec 3.10.x, I had luck with `and_wrap_original`. https://rspec.info/documentation/3.3/rspec-mocks/RSpec/Mocks/MessageExpectation.html#and_wrap_original-instance_method

Answer (score 5):

The following worked for me:

```rb
original = thing.method(:foo)
expect(thing).to receive(:foo) do |_params|
  # check params
  expect(params).to include(something)

  # then
  original.call(params)
end
```